# How do I remove an attachment on a Jira ticket?

Tags: jira

The permission "Delete all Attachments" is granted to the group "jira-users".   I am member of "jira-users".  Though, I do not see a way to remove an attatchment (a screenshot actually).

Comment: Remember that permission to do this is granted in Permission Scheme, and that different JIRA projects can have different permission schemes. So you might be able to do it in one project but not another.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I am by no means a JIRA expert, but on our instance (v4.2.4-b591#591), there is a drop down arrow next to the "+" icon to add an attachment.  In that drop down, there is a "Manage Attachments" option.  You should be able to figure it out from there...

[image: jira screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

As of October, 2015, it's changed a little and I thought I would post a new answer since this is the first Google result!

According to a forum post, the only way to remove attachments is to open the issue in the "Issue" view and not the "Projects" view, click on the issue, scroll down to the attachments, and then hit the trashcan icon when scrolling over the image.

Source: [Jira Forum](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/171582/how-do-i-remove-an-attachment)

> It's not directly possible in the greenhopper detail view. You first have to open the issue in the normal JIRA issue detail view through clicking on the issue key in the greenhopper detail view. In the normal JIRA view you should see a trash can icon if you hover over an attachment. If not, you should check your permissions

Comment: If no trashcan icon is visible, you don't have perms. (This is what I learned today.)